# No compiler found in your classpath! Axis 1.4 Tomcat 7 Java 8

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, axis

I have this error when I call an Axis service since I migrate from Java 6 to Java 8 (the webApp). It appears only on the first call.

```
ERROR org.apache.axis.components.compiler.Javac: No compiler found in your classpath!  (you may need to add 'tools.jar')
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main$Result cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Adding the jar JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar to the classpath doesn't change anything. The JAVA_HOME always point to a JDK.

Seems to work in Java 7.

Comment: Add it to your application's classpath or the `java` call then.

Comment: This is not a dupe of 34311113 but it is of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965823/tools-jar-missing-but-only-on-the-very-first-call-tomcat-8-java-8-axis . The compiler *is* there but it changed in Java8 and axis apparently hasn't adapted to it; see particularly the update in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29658294/2868801 .

Comment: Thanks, It seems to be the same issue as stackoverflow.com/a/29658294/2868801 but using Tomcat8. There is no good answer to the problem with Tomcat8, maybe there are with Tomcat7... I can't downgrade the JDK version.

Answer (score 0):

If no compiler is found, you are probably using a `JRE` instead of a `JDK` .

Only the `Java Development Kit` contains a java compiler.

Comment: Thanks but I use a JDK